# Black screen while installing ubuntu 13.10 HELP!

Tags: boot

I just bought an alienware M17x R4 (NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 765M  and Intel Haswell graphic cards), I am trying to install ubuntu 13.10, just after booting on the CD and choosing the installation option the screen goes black, i want to use the CLI option (F4 modes) but i have only 3 options :

1. Normal
2. User drive update disc
3. OEM install (only manfacturers)

Has anyone a similar problem before? Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for the black screen of death, after booting from the CD i followed the steps bellow  :

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd>
2. <kbd>F6</kbd> different options --> nomodeset
3. Install ubuntu

It works just fine for me.